# How to find derived classes in a solution in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, inheritance, architecture, class-diagram

In Visual Studio 2013 when I go to Class View, then search for a class, then expand "Derived Types" folder it shows me only the classes derived from this class in the current project, but not the whole solution. Is there a way to find all the derived classes in the solution in Visual Studio 2013 or perhaps some plugins? The language in focus is C++ (unmanaged).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question. So far I am making do with a regular expression that matches part of the declaration of the derived class:

```
:\s*(public|private|protected)?\s+ClassName
```

For example when searching for all classes derived from class A in the following:

```
class B : public A {};
```

The regular expression tries to match the `: public A`. Note this will not work when A is not first base class in the list of base classes. Also does not work for indirect descendants.